# Installing Node.js on server accessing node from another computer on the same network

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have uploaded node.js on my server. How do I call node.js from another computer on the same network? I created node-test.js and run it on the server which will show Hello World. But when I go to the url on another computer on the same network the page is not found? Will someone please help me with this?

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World!n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: go to cmd prompt, check ipconfig, then use that ip with port number 1337, use only listen(1337) .

Comment: as per production means, do you have any DNS?

Comment: As per discussion, you want in production(means every one should access), for that you should have own Domain, like facebook.com, gmail.com. you have to buy domain in some server(supports node), then you can deploy your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to cmd prompt, check ipconfig, then use that ip with port number 1337, use only listen(1337) .

Comment: what do u mean use only listen 1337?

Comment: ughhh i thought it was working I cant write code on the computer that does not have node? I thought by calling the port and ip everything would still run but instead when I run node node-test.js it says Error 0x2 starting node.exe node-test.js